# Почему не отображаются теги option в select в Joomla 3?

Tags: joomla, form, html-select

Joomla 3.4.

Есть стандартная форма контактов, и в ней я добавляю обычный выпадающий список по типу:

```html
<select id="newField">
  <option value="0">выбрать</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
<select>
```

Если просмотреть код страницы, все `option` выводятся, но при нажатии на `select` они не отображаются. В console тоже нет никаких ошибок.

Comment: Ссылку на страницу с данной ошибкой можете предоставить?

Comment: Проблема решена.